# how can I format my date in php to have the query new Date() format?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a php script that returns the date of the server:

```
<?php
   echo date('D, d M y H:i:s a');
?>
```

but when I print this value on the client site I get:

```
Tue, 29 Sep 15 16:19:28 pm
```

But instead I need the date in this format:

```
Tue Sep 29 2015 16:18:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

How should I modify my php script then to have it like this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to study the PHP docs concerning [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and its methods to understand what you need to do in a simple, neat way.

Comment: `echo (new DateTime())->format('r');`

Comment: @jonbaldie thank you that's it, please add it as a comment so I can accept this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo (new DateTime())->format('r');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$datestring = "26-08-2015 03:35:28";        //date as string            
$date = new DateTime($datestring);  //String to datetime conversion
$date = $date->format('D d M y H:i:s O e');   //format the date
echo $date;
```

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is the manual link.  Timezone you have to set.

Output will look like `Wed 26 Aug 15 03:35:28 +0200 Europe/Paris`

Answer (score -1):

Go to the very bottom of this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: I can't see how timezone setting can be related to the OP issue. And curiously, there is a deprecated, downvoted-to-the-underground user note. I'm sure there is a good reason why it was downvoted this much.